# Magento 2 | Prevent saving the completed state on the order

Tags: magento2, orders, shipping, invoice, state

In Magento2, when the payment of the order is made by credit card, the invoice is immediately generated. This involves saving the order with a **completed** state as soon as the shipment is created.

Is it possible to prevent the saving of the order state as **completed** when creating the shipment?

Thanks!